# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio: Display row in message after running script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get SQL errors and often times I will get something like

> Msg 50000, Level 11, State 1, Line 59

where line 59 in this case is causing my problem.

But then I have to tediously search through my code and count down line 59.

Is there anyway to set an option to show lines numbers in the message box or in the sql window itself so it's easier to find the row causing an error in my script?

Thanks!

Comment: You did not provide the script. And you should tell us what you did so we know what you did to fix the issue, that is of course after providing the script.

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking for.  Read the question.  He's asking how to turn on a feature within SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

In the bottom right hand corner of SSMS is a label with that information. You can also turn on line numbers.

```
Tools -> Options - -> TextEditor -> All Languages -> Display -> LineNumbers
```

Comment: On my version of SSMS it is  Tools | Options | TextEditor | Transact-SQL | General | Line Numbers

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just double-click the error message and it will automatically jump to your code and highlight the error for you.